# TextView not align with center in runtime

Tags: android

I have a XML layout wrote like this:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="190dp"
        android:background="#a49881">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="315dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/header"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment_platform_body"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">
        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

In my activity I added a TextView Object in runtime but is not align with center. I try added GRAVITY in LinearLayout rutime but not worked too.

```
TextView textView = new TextView(getContext());
    LinearLayout gridPartnerLayout = (LinearLayout) getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.partner_line, null);
    gridPartnerLayout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    gridPartnerLayout.addView(textView);
```

If I add a TextView Object in XML it's work perfectly

Like this:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="190dp"
        android:background="#a49881">
    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="315dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/header"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment_platform_body"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/boarder_shape"
                android:text="XXX"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Why my textView not align? Will it be android bug?

Comment: Attach a layout params for the text view.

Comment: What's inside `partner_line` layout?

Comment: @SergeyGlotov only scrollview and linearlayout as I show up

Comment: Then this line should give you a crash in runtime `LinearLayout gridPartnerLayout = (LinearLayout) getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.partner_line, null);` because you are trying to cast ScrollView to LinearLayout. You didn't say anything about crash, so I think there is something another in it :)
And you didn't show to us creation of textView

Comment: @SergeyGlotov sorry about this :( a updated my code.

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin worked :D Thank's

Comment: You are adding it to parent view. Get LinearLayout with id `fragment_platform_body` and add view to it.